# How do to the opposite of "row_number() over (partition by [Col] order by [Col])"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, row-number

I am trying to combine duplicate entries in a data table and give them a new number.

Here is a example data set ([runnable copy](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81485/query-for-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-12695858?opt.textResults=true))

```
declare @tmpTable table
    (ID Varchar(1), 
     First varchar(4), 
     Last varchar(5), 
     Phone varchar(13),
     NonKeyField varchar(4))

insert into @tmpTable select 'A', 'John', 'Smith', '(555)555-1234', 'ASDF'
insert into @tmpTable select 'B', 'John', 'Smith', '(555)555-1234', 'GHJK'
insert into @tmpTable select 'C', 'Jane', 'Smith', '(555)555-1234', 'QWER'
insert into @tmpTable select 'D', 'John', 'Smith', '(555)555-1234', 'RTYU'
insert into @tmpTable select 'E', 'Bill', 'Blake', '(555)555-0000', 'BVNM'
insert into @tmpTable select 'F', 'Bill', 'Blake', '(555)555-0000', '%^&*'
insert into @tmpTable select 'G', 'John', 'Smith', '(555)555-1234', '!#RF'

select row_number() over (partition by First, Last, Phone order by ID) NewIDNum, *  
from @tmpTable order by ID
```

Right now it gives me the results

```
NewIDNum             ID   First Last  Phone         NonKeyField
-------------------- ---- ----- ----- ------------- -----------
1                    A    John  Smith (555)555-1234 ASDF
2                    B    John  Smith (555)555-1234 GHJK
1                    C    Jane  Smith (555)555-1234 QWER
3                    D    John  Smith (555)555-1234 RTYU
1                    E    Bill  Blake (555)555-0000 BVNM
2                    F    Bill  Blake (555)555-0000 %^&*
4                    G    John  Smith (555)555-1234 !#RF
```

However that is the opposite of what I want, the `NewIDNum` resets its counter ever time it finds a new combination of the key. I want all of the same combination to have the same ID. So if it was behaving the way I wanted I would get the following results

```
NewIDNum             ID   First Last  Phone         NonKeyField
-------------------- ---- ----- ----- ------------- -----------
1                    A    John  Smith (555)555-1234 ASDF
1                    B    John  Smith (555)555-1234 GHJK
2                    C    Jane  Smith (555)555-1234 QWER
1                    D    John  Smith (555)555-1234 RTYU
3                    E    Bill  Blake (555)555-0000 BVNM
3                    F    Bill  Blake (555)555-0000 %^&*
1                    G    John  Smith (555)555-1234 !#RF
```

What is the correct way to get the results I want?

---

**I did not include this requirement in the original post**:  I need the `NewIDNum` to produce the same numbers on subsequent runs of this query for the existing rows if more rows get added (assuming all new rows will have a higher ID "value" if a order by is done on the ID column)

So if at a latter date the following was done

```
insert into @tmpTable select 'H', 'John', 'Smith', '(555)555-1234', '4321'
insert into @tmpTable select 'I', 'Jake', 'Jons', '(555)555-1234', '1234'
insert into @tmpTable select 'J', 'John', 'Smith', '(555)555-1234', '2345'
```

running the correct query again would give

```
NewIDNum             ID   First Last  Phone         NonKeyField
-------------------- ---- ----- ----- ------------- -----------
1                    A    John  Smith (555)555-1234 ASDF
1                    B    John  Smith (555)555-1234 GHJK
2                    C    Jane  Smith (555)555-1234 QWER
1                    D    John  Smith (555)555-1234 RTYU
3                    E    Bill  Blake (555)555-0000 BVNM
3                    F    Bill  Blake (555)555-0000 %^&*
1                    G    John  Smith (555)555-1234 !#RF
1                    H    John  Smith (555)555-1234 4321
4                    I    Jake  Jons  (555)555-1234 1234
1                    J    John  Smith (555)555-1234 2345
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `dense_rank()`:

```
dense_rank() over (order by First, Last, Phone) as NewIDNum
```

In response to your comment, you could sort on the minimum of the old `Id` column per group of rows with the same `(First, Last, Phone)` combination:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  dense_rank() over (order by min_id) as new_id
        ,       *
        from    (
                select  min(id) over (
                            partition by First, Last, Phone) as min_id
                ,       *
                from    @tmpTable 
                ) as sub1
        ) as sub3
order by
        new_id
```

Comment: Can I get it to be ordered by the old ID? I need the new IDs to produce the same numbers for the existing rows if more rows get added (assuming new rows will have a higher ID "value" if a `order by` is done on the ID column)

Comment: To your update: Adding the "Jake Jons" test causes him to have a DR of 2 and John and Jane Smith's DR both change by 1.

Comment: Updated to assign a dense rank based on the lowest `id` per `(First, Last, Phone)` group.

Comment: I figured out [my own method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12696262/80274) using group by, but running your query and mine next to each other, yours is faster by execution time %. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is sub3 nessasary? why not put the final order by inside sub3 and remove the outer most layer (I am not going to even use the order by in my real query (it will be feeding a `Insert Into`), but I am curious).

Comment: Sub3 prevents repetition of the definition of `new_id`.  If you don't need the order by, you can definitely omit it.  As you could see with a simple test :)

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Andomar's original answer -- this will work on your updated requirements (though this won't likely scale nicely)

```
select
    DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY IdRank, First, Last, Phone) AS NewIDNum,
    ID,
    First,
    Last,
    Phone,
    NonKeyField
from
(
    select
        MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY First, Last, Phone) as IdRank,
        *
    from
        @tmpTable
) as x
order by
    ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Andomar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695897/80274) as a jumping off point I solved it myself

```
select sub1.rn, tt.*
from @tmpTable tt
inner join (
    select row_number() over (order by min(ID)) as rn, first, last, phone
    from @tmpTable
    group by first, last, phone
    ) as sub1 on tt.first = sub1.first and tt.last = sub1.last and tt.phone = sub1.phone
```

this produces

```
rn                   ID   First Last  Phone         NonKeyField
-------------------- ---- ----- ----- ------------- -----------
1                    A    John  Smith (555)555-1234 ASDF
1                    B    John  Smith (555)555-1234 GHJK
1                    D    John  Smith (555)555-1234 RTYU
1                    G    John  Smith (555)555-1234 !#RF
1                    H    John  Smith (555)555-1234 4321
1                    J    John  Smith (555)555-1234 2345
2                    C    Jane  Smith (555)555-1234 QWER
3                    E    Bill  Blake (555)555-0000 BVNM
3                    F    Bill  Blake (555)555-0000 %^&*
4                    I    Jake  Jons  (555)555-1234 1234
```

---

Looking at the SQL Execution plan, Adnomar's answer will run quicker for larger data sets than mine. (53% execution time VS 47% execution time when run next to each other and "Include actual execution plan" checked.

Comment: You're querying your table variable twice which is less optimal than @Andomar's solution.

Comment: That explains my slower execution time. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
select dense_rank() over (order by First, Last, Phone) NewIDNum, *  
from @tmpTable order by ID
```

Comment: See my comment to Andomar's answer.